# Adding new observations with a character value in one column and zero values in another to a data frame

Tags: r

I am currently working with a dataset regarding densities (trees per hectare, TPH) of tree species at particular sites. In order to calculate average densities of all sites, I need to include values of zero for tree species that are not present in a given site but present in others. Here is code that simulates a data frame similar to mine.

```
# Define number of rows and levels for the grouping variable
set.seed(120)
n_rows <- 10
site_levels <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

# Create a map of sites and species that can be absent
absent_species <- list(
  North = c("Quercus alba", "Betula papyrifera"),
  South = c("Pinus strobus", "Tsuga canadensis"),
  East = c("Acer rubrum"),
  West = c("Quercus alba", "Tsuga canadensis")
)

# Define species pool and pre-fill empty site vectors
species_pool <- c("Acer rubrum", "Quercus alba", "Pinus strobus", "Tsuga canadensis", "Betula papyrifera")
site_species <- lapply(site_levels, function(site) character(0))

# Simulate Site column
data <- data.frame(Site = sample(site_levels, size = n_rows, replace = TRUE))

# Loop through rows and assign unique species per site
for (i in 1:n_rows) {
  site <- data$Site[i]
  absent_list <- absent_species[[site]]
  species_pool_filtered <- setdiff(species_pool, absent_list)
  
  # Check if all species have been used at this site
  if (length(site_species[[site]]) == length(species_pool_filtered)) {
    # No more species available, skip this row
    next
  }
  
  # Choose a random species from the filtered pool
  species <- sample(species_pool_filtered, size = 1, replace = FALSE)
  
  # Assign species and add it to the site's list
  data$Species[i] <- species
  site_species[[site]] <- c(site_species[[site]], species)
}

# Simulate tree densities with some variation by site
data$TPH <- rnorm(n_rows, 
                  mean = c(500, 250, 100, 350)[match(data$Site, site_levels)],
                  sd = c(100, 50, 25, 75)[match(data$Site, site_levels)])

# Print the simulated dataframe
print(data)
```

You will notice that not all tree species are present in each plot, which could normally be ignored but the fact that they are absent is important, so they should be added as a new observation with a TPH value of 0. Is there an easy way to add in the species that are absent from a given site but present in others, and assign the new observation a TPH value of 0?

I've attempted to calculate means and standard errors of density manually and simply dividing the sum of all densities by the number of sites present to account for values of zero of a species at a site where it was not present. I was able to calculate the correct mean this way but cannot compute standard errors.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is with `dplyr::right_join`. First, define a dataframe with all possible combinations of sites and species:

```
comb <- expand.grid(Site = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                    Species = c("Quercus alba", "Acer rubrum", "Tsuga canadensis"))
```

Then use `right_join` to create all missing combinations in the target dataframe, ending with `dplyr::mutate` and `tidyr::replace_na` to replace `NA` to 0:

```
data1 <- data %>% 
            right_join(comb, by = c("Site", "Species")) %>% 
            mutate(TPH = replace_na(TPH, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good opportunity to use `complete` from `tidyr`.

Here, you can specify you want all combinations of `Site` and `Species`, and then use `fill` for `TPH` to be set to 0 for missing combinations.

```
library(tidyr)

data |>
  complete(Site, Species, fill = list(TPH = 0))
```

**Output**

```
   Site  Species             TPH
   <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 A     Acer rubrum          0 
 2 A     Betula papyrifera    0 
 3 A     Pinus strobus      552.
 4 A     Quercus alba       480.
 5 A     Tsuga canadensis   456.
 6 B     Acer rubrum          0 
 7 B     Betula papyrifera  227.
 8 B     Pinus strobus        0 
 9 B     Quercus alba         0 
10 B     Tsuga canadensis   238.
# ℹ 11 more rows
```